# Amazon Event Bridge is not triggering my lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

In event bridge I set up a rule to call a lambda function, when the "Object created" is triggered in s3.

[image]

In my bucket I activated the event bridge:

[image]

The problem is, my function never gets triggered, when I upload a file in the management console to my bucket:

[image]

What am I missing to make this simple example work?

Comment: Can you try with the bucket name, instead of the ARN?

Comment: Did you set permissions for your function so that EB can invoke it?

Comment: As Paolo said in your event pattern, replace the bucket ARN with the bucket name only. Also rather than checking the lamda invocation, click on the "Metrics for the rule" to see if the rule was triggered or not. This helps you troubleshoot if the problem is between S3 and EventBridge or EventBridge and Lambda.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm in the exact same situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not required to use EventBridge, in this case you may send S3 event notifications directly into a Lambda function.

Following this documentation, pick the event types, then select "Lambda function" as your destination and select your Lambda function that will accept these events.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enable-event-notifications.html

You may follow these two tutorials as an example:

- [Using an Amazon S3 trigger to invoke a Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)
- [Using an Amazon S3 trigger to create thumbnail images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-tutorial.html)